# Fast API accepting empty value for mandatory field

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have a POST Api and I am passing a mandatory string parameter to it, say **test_field**. When I run the API, and do not pass any value to the **test_field** it does not allow the API to execute since it is a required parameter and I am not passing the required value.

But when I am using the curl command to call the API and sending an empty value to the query parameter it is accepting it, and giving a 200 response.

"POST /api/v1/test_api?test_field= HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

My test_field is a string field - **test_field: str**

Although when I am using a Body(...) parameter - **test_field : str = Body(...)**, the curl command denies the operation and says that required field is missing.

How is this possible? How can the API accept empty value for a mandatory field?

FastAPI version being used: 0.95.0
Pydantic: 1.10.7
Python: 3.9.16

Comment: An empty string is still a string. It would help, if you posted a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) though.

Answer (score 2):

When the request, **POST /api/v1/test_api?test_field=** , is made, the **test_field** parameter is set to empty string. So, in order to ensure that non-empty strings are only accepted, you might want to use Pydantic's type [constr](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#arguments-to-constr) and set the **min_length** attribute.

So, it will be:

```
from pydantic import constr

...
... test_field: constr(min_length=1) ...
```